# org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication Application startup failed:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wildfly, cas, wildfly-14

I'm getting below exception while deploying spring boot application in WildFly14. But same is deployed fine in WildFly10.

spring boot version is 1.5.18
have the same issue with spring 2x as well.

The application I'm deploying is cas overly downloaded from https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/tree/5.3

```
20:04:32,506 DEBUG [org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) JNDI lookup for name [banner.location] threw NamingException with message: banner.location -- service jboss.naming.context.java."banner.location". Returning null.
20:04:32,506 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Could not find key 'banner.location' in any property source
20:04:32,522 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Application failed to start with classpath: unknown
20:04:32,522 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Application startup failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils.invokeVfsMethod(VfsUtils.java:100)
    at org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils.getFile(VfsUtils.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.io.VfsResource.getFile(VfsResource.java:95)
    at org.apereo.cas.util.CasVersion.getDateTime(CasVersion.java:59)
    at org.apereo.cas.util.SystemUtils.getSystemInfo(SystemUtils.java:50)
    at org.apereo.cas.util.spring.boot.AbstractCasBanner.collectEnvironmentInfo(AbstractCasBanner.java:63)
    at org.apereo.cas.util.spring.boot.AbstractCasBanner.printBanner(AbstractCasBanner.java:37)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.print(SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.printBanner(SpringApplication.java:505)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:203)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$658/1543581401.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$659/1515086559.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$659/1515086559.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$659/1515086559.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$659/1515086559.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

20:04:32,522 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."cas.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."cas.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils.invokeVfsMethod(VfsUtils.java:100)
    at org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils.getFile(VfsUtils.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.io.VfsResource.getFile(VfsResource.java:95)
    at org.apereo.cas.util.CasVersion.getDateTime(CasVersion.java:59)
    at org.apereo.cas.util.SystemUtils.getSystemInfo(SystemUtils.java:50)
    at org.apereo.cas.util.spring.boot.AbstractCasBanner.collectEnvironmentInfo(AbstractCasBanner.java:63)
    at org.apereo.cas.util.spring.boot.AbstractCasBanner.printBanner(AbstractCasBanner.java:37)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.print(SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.printBanner(SpringApplication.java:505)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:203)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$658/1543581401.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$659/1515086559.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$659/1515086559.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$659/1515086559.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$659/1515086559.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    ... 10 more

20:04:32,523 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"cas.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class"}}
```

Comment: Sometime using a wrong version of java might trigger such large amount of error. CAS 5.3.x only supports `Java 8` as far as I know.  Any idea what version of java are wildfly 14 / 10 using?

Comment: @NgSekLong I'm using Java 8 only. I'm able to deploy other spring boot application except the one comes with CAS.